# Confusion regarding users signing up multiple times

Tags: discussion, new-users, login

I've seen on several occasions cases where new users sign up to StackOverflow, and sign up again using an identical user name some time later.

While I don't think preventing people from signing up multiple times is a bad idea, I am wondering if there could be a way to suggest to a user that "someone with that name already exists, are you sure you want to sign up with that name?" That way, we give the user a chance to log into an existing account, rather than making a new account from scratch.

This isn't a huge problem, and I don't know if this is a limitation with OpenID or not, but is this an issue worth solving?

Answer (score 1):

"Sign up" is kind of a loaded term -- you realize we allow 100% anonymous participation, like Wikipedia, right?

In other words, you don't need to register or validate an email or anything -- you can ask as many questions, or answer as many questions, as you like.. with just a temporary browser cookie, even.